# jQuery Toggle Items in Array

Tags: jquery

So, I have a bunch of elements that I want the user to be able to select and deselect. However it doesn't seem to be working, I need to store data so I can send them to the server later so I'm doing it by an array. This is my code so far.

Javascript

```
var items = new Array();
function selectItem(element){

var itemName = element.find(".item").val();

if(jQuery.inArray(className, item)){
    element.removeClass("selected");
    items.splice($.inArray(itemName, items), 1);
}else{
    element.addClass("selected");
    items.push(itemName);
}
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="Item" onClick="selectItem($(this))">
</div>
```

It doesn't seem to be doing the if statement and I'm not sure why.

Comment: where is `className` and `item` is defined in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery **[`jQuery.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)** method returns the index of the element if found or `-1` in case element not found. So change the if condition as follows

```
if(jQuery.inArray(className, item) > -1)
```